# Is there a way to count distinct number at granular level to aggregate level with multiple condition in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I have a situation wherein I want to count the distinct customer.in a table with a condition per product. I want a summary count of distinct customers per product.

I created a parameter which shows what I want to be included and what should not be counted. The rules applied on the status are written below:

```
IF ATTR([Product]) = 'A' AND COUNT([Record]) >= 10 THEN 'Should be counted'
 
ELSEIF ATTR([Product]) = 'B' AND COUNT([Record]) >= 5 THEN 'Should be counted'
 
ELSEIF ATTR([Product]) = 'C' AND COUNT([Record]) >= 3 THEN 'Should be counted'
 
ELSE 'Should not be counted'
 
END
```

Since the data is transaction per row. Think of record as purchases. I am only interested in the right side of the crosstab CountD column. Please refer to the image below.

[image]

How can I achieve a summary using distinct customers per product considering only repeat purchases for product A >=10, product B>=5 and product C>=3.. If I remove the customer name everything will be aggregated and undesirable.

[image]

I want my output to be like the one below.

[image]

Any help will be so much appreciated. Can someone share/teach me the steps to achieve the kind of output that I desire.

Thank you in advance

Joseph

Comment: You've described everything except the most crucial piece. What does a record look like? What columns? and what does a record represent? Some detailed transaction or a summary of many transactions?

Comment: Didn't it serve your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Though it would have been better if you'd shared the data structure, yet I think the following calculated field may help

```
{FIXED [Product] : COUNTD([CUSTOMER])}
```

Needless to say, If you want counting of filtered records, you should include `[STATUS]` field on filters shelf and `Add to Context` after right clicking it in the filters shelf itself **(because order of operations of LOD calculations is higher than normal filters but lower than context filters)**